# Blank white page after Magento migration

Tags: magento

some please help.

I migrated from one server to another.

One the new server, I edited the local.xml with the new database detail.

When I go to site all I see is a blank white page.

I have commented out the compiler but still showing white page.

Please what do I do?

do I have edit the config file?
do i have to increase php memory limit?

please help!

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Blank page means there is some PHP fatal error.

So dig into your server error logs and check what error has been logged.

Post that error so as to comment further.

Comment: Yes, and to help further you can uncomment the line ini_set('display_errors', 1); in index.php as this will usually get errors to display on screen and to help your debugging if you don't have server access.

Comment: This is not an answer...i got blank page also and no errors on apache logs...magento doesnt have Errors settings?, i have enabled it but still getting this sh**t